# Configuration files : JS vs INI

Tags: javascript, php, json, security, ini

I need to implement configuration files for an application im developing.

I was wondering whether it is better to use INI files or JS files(JSON data)
for the configuration  files.

What are the security concerns? Could a file permission be set to the js files that a user cannot retrieve them via the browser but the php can read them?

Comment: You realize both are just plain text files right? Neither has anything to do with the security of your server - it's how you configure the user/group permissions and whether the files are available under the docroot that matters.

Comment: `.json` is more flexible, widely supported, than `.ini` which is restricted except from custom extensions to `.ini` format. However for simple coinfiguration .`.ini` seems fine. All are text formats, no difference in security, except if one would like to have encrypted config files, instead of plain text

Comment: The configuration file might contain sensitive information. That just being out in open view  is a security concern.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to handle that kind of configuration is to keep it outside of your public directory, so that users won't be able to access it.

Generally in web applications you have web-accessible directory. For example: `web/` in Symfony 2.x and `public/` in Laravel 4/5. In these folders you would usually find index.php file which user runs when accesses your website. If you move your file outside of this folder - (`cd ..`) - into your application root directory where you might see directories like `vendor/` then here you could store files which ordinary user would not be able to download just using some link to the file.

About file extension. Actually lately it has become quite popular to name your config files in "dot" format. For example: `production` or `.my_config` which not only protects you from users accidentally downloading files (since dot files are usually not accessible), but it also lets you keep your config files out of version control software such as git, so your passwords won't end up on github.

Comment: Good point about GitHub - I'm still old skool enough to use SVN on a local staging server so that possibility hadn't even occurred to me :|

Comment: @CD001, happens. SVN keeps track of those too?

Comment: Worst case with SVN though is that the passwords in the config files are on a local staging server in the office - not uploaded to the GitHub cloud. It'll quite happily synch up your `.htpasswd` or `.htaccess` files though so I don't think `.config` would phase it - you have to manually remove them from version control.

Comment: Not very nice. Push for switch to git :)

Comment: The problem is if i configure .htaccess to restrict access to dot files, even php cant access them.

Comment: @LukeNukem, as it was mentioned in the answer - you really shouldn't keep any config files including dot files withing the publicly available folder.